# MySQL: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use **in subquery** and **limit** in left join condition but I am getting sql error.

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `MessageThreads`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` in 
  (select SenderId from Messages where 
     Messages.MessageThreadId =  MessageThreads.MessageThreadId 
     order by Messages.MessageId desc limit 1)
```

Table Structure:

**MessageThreads**

```
----------------------
|    MessageThreadId  |  
----------------------
```

**users**

```
----------------------
|   id    |   name   |
----------------------
```

**Messages**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|   MessageId  |   SenderId   |  MessageThreadId   |    Msg   |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

My purpose: I want to get all MessageThreads with user detail of the one latest message received in Messages table.

Is this possible to implement this way or what should be best approach to do this?

I'll really appreciate any contribution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the max(id)

```
SELECT * FROM `MessageThreads`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = 
   (select SenderId from Messages where 
        Messages.MessageThreadId =  MessageThreads.MessageThreadId 
        and Messages.MessageId = (select max(Messages.MessageId) from Messages));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT mt.*, u.* 
FROM MessageThreads AS mt
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT MessageThreadId, MAX(MessageId) AS MessageId
   FROM Messages
   GROUP BY MessageThreadId
) AS m ON mt.MessageThreadId = m.MessageThreadId
JOIN Messages AS m2 ON m2.MessageId = m.MessageId
JOIN Users AS u ON u.Id = m2.SenderId
```

This query will select the user being related to the latest message per message thread.